# Remove highlighted html code while saving - highlight_file() php

Tags: php, ajax, file, syntax-highlighting, highlight

In my application I'm displaying the content of a file named *test.php* using ajax to a table with id `fileContents`. I'm using `highlight_file()` to highlight the code and it is working fine. I have a Save button in the page to save the div content back to the file.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'test_file.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
          filePath: 'test.php'
       },
       success: function(data) {
            $('#fileContents').html(data);
       }
    });
});
function saveFileContents() {
    console.log($('#fileContentDiv').html());
}
</script>

<table id="fileContents">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveFileContents()">
```

**test_file.php**

```
<tr>
<td>
<div id="fileContentDiv" contenteditable="true">
<?php
echo highlight_file( $_POST['filePath'] );
?>
</td>
</tr>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
echo "hai";
?>
```

I tried to edit the div and add a new line of code to the second last line `$i=0;` and when I click the Save button, I got console like this:

```
<code><span style="color: #000000">
<br><br>&lt;?php&nbsp;</span></code><div><code><span style="color: #000000">echo&nbsp;"hai";</span></code></div><div><code><span style="color: #000000">$i =0;</span></code></div><div><code><span style="color: #000000">?&gt;</span></code>&nbsp;</div>
```

I need to save the php code only back to the file(along with line breaks). I tried using `$('#fileContent').text()`. But it is saving the content in one line.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.